# How to log Redshift recent SQL queries with actual parameters values

Tags: prepared-statement, amazon-redshift

When I'm logging queries executed on Amazon Redshift by querying `STL_QUERY` table,
I get the prepared statement query, without the parameters values, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE ts=$1
```

I want to know what are the real parameter values.

Is there a way to know that?

Comment: my query contains a timestamp, and I suspect that it is not performed on the timestamp I send (probably because of timezone issue).
I send the same query with the same timestamp to redshift from different servers, and the results are different.

Comment: It might be the case as JDBS has its own rules about client side timezone. Did you try to specify the timezone with CONVERT_TIMEZONE function?

Comment: I didn't, and I didn't know about this function. I will try it when I'll return to this task (it might take several weeks...)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that `stl_querytext` would give you the query after the parameters have been replaced with actual values.